# Monotonicity of incomplete Gamma function

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

For given $x \geq 0$, a function $f(a)$ is defined as

$f(a) = \frac{\Gamma(a, x)}{\Gamma(a)},$

where $\Gamma(a, x)$ is the upper incomplete Gamma function. I need to prove $f(a)$ is a monotonic function with $a \in [0,1]$. I have tried to compute the first derivative of $f(a)$, but I could not prove this derivative is nonnegative. Could you please help me?

Comment: Could you please include the derivative of $f$ that you calculated?

Comment: @supinf. The derivative is so ..... awful !

Answer (score 1):

*Partial answer.* For $x>0$,
$$
\frac{{\Gamma (a,x)}}{{\Gamma (a)}} = \frac{1}{{\Gamma (a)}}\int_x^{+\infty}  {e^{ - t} t^{a - 1} dt}  .
$$
For $t\geq x\geq 1$,
$$
a \mapsto t^{a-1} ,\quad a \mapsto \frac{1}{{\Gamma (a)}}
$$
are monotonically increasing functions of $a$ on $[0,1]$, whence $\frac{{\Gamma (a,x)}}{{\Gamma (a)}}$ is monotonically increasing on $[0,1]$ for any fixed $x\geq 1$.